# Second answer to own question

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

Yesterday, I [asked a rather tricky question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680694/pointers-in-pure-functions/) that was really bugging me. I found one solution that is strictly Standard-conforming, but also has severe limitations.

Another user provided a solution that breaks the Standard by tricking the compiler with mis-matching interfaces.

Today, I found a solution that works very well, without ugly tricks, by abusing a particular intrinsic. All three solutions are different, so I posted the latest solution as an individual answer.

Now, I have second thoughts about that. My first answer is probably the safest bet (though limited), so I should better keep it. My second answer, however, is the one I find best.

How should I proceed? Should I merge my answers, or should I leave it as it is?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Leave it as is. There is nothing wrong with multiple answers if they are substantially different. And it allows users to actually vote for the individual solutions (up or down).